# Fetch rows with primary keys within range

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, database-design, query-optimization

Is it possible to efficiently do range scans on a big table(may be a billion rows) under heavy load to **fetch all rows with primary keys within range**. The primary key is of `BIGINT` type. Rows are very short just another `INT` field besides the primary key. Only this type of queries are performed on this table.

Anyway to optimize such queries, or table? May be I can store the rows always sorted, so that range scanning is easier??

Is it possible at all to do such queries with a good performance on a big table ?

Answer (score 1):

Primary key column(s) are automatically indexed, so access to a range should perform very well. Use a `BETWEEN` condition:

```
select * from mytable
where id between ? and ?
```

Of course, if the range is large, performance will be slow simply due to the huge number of rows being returned.

Also, if the size of the range is beyond a certain limit (optimizer will decide, but typically 1/11th of the total rows) the index will not be used and a full tale scan will be done instead, because it's actually faster than using an index if the percentage of rows being accessed is large enough.

When in doubt, run an `EXPLAIN` on the query to show how access is being done. If it's using the index, chances are it's as fast as it can be.

Comment: No, I don't want to fetch entire range also, I would limit it maximum 1000 rows(that's maximum & rare) & range would never cover even 1/1000th of all rows. Can the sort the rows & would that help in performance ?

Comment: Don't sort. Just use the query in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think my statement was a bit ambiguous, I meant storing rows in the table sorted  in order of primary keys, so that range scanning was pretty easier for MySQL.

Comment: Btw, also to clarify these `BIGINT`s(which are primary keys) are actually composites made from two *4 byte `INT`s*. I need to store lists of topics(upto 500) followed by users in my app. So there are 2 ways either I just make a composite of (userId+topicId) & store the resultant `BIGINT` as primary key & use range scans as explained above or otherwise some also do it like, using two separate fields for userId & topicId & do queries like `select * from mytable where userid=?`. But 2nd approach doesn't make any primary keys in the table & so I am not sure if it gives same or better performance?!